# How to use array values as matrix coordinates to insert values in the matrix

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays x and y of size 4013. The values of x array are row indices and of y array are column indices. I want to create a matrix of size 512*512 and insert values using x and y indices. How can I do this ?

Comment: Those `x` and `y` would act as the indices, but what values would you put in there in the matrix and what about the indices of the matrix that won't be indexed with them?

Comment: I am dealing with an gray scale image(matrix of 512*512). At first i have extracted those pixel locations having value 255(logical 1) using find() function from the image in x and y array. x contains row value of that pixel and y contains column value. Now i want to create a new matrix and put 255(logical 1) value in the row and column location of x and y, other location values will be 0.

Comment: Use @Naveh's solution with `val=255;`

Comment: I missed this comment about the 255 value earlier. Edited the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to turn index vectors into matrix indices. For example:

```
x = randi(512, 4000, 1);
y = randi(512, 4000, 1);
val = 255;
mat = zeros(512, 512);
mat(sub2ind(size(mat), y, x)) = val;
```